# Is there a name for $Z_{1}(|\mathrm{GHZ}\rangle)$?

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement

The GHZ state is defined as $|\mathrm{GHZ}\rangle = \frac{|000\rangle + |111\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$. Is there a name for the phase flipped GHZ state, i.e. $Z_1(|\mathrm{GHZ}\rangle)=\frac{|000\rangle - |111\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$ ?

Comment: I don't think so. You could call the two states as $|\mathrm{GHZ}_{\pm}\rangle$. The important think (perhaps) is that both these states are in the same entanglement class (the two entanglement classes being the one of GHZ and W states, for example, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenberger%E2%80%93Horne%E2%80%93Zeilinger_state#Definition)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @keisuke.akira already mentioned, and as far as I am aware, there is not really an agreed upon name for such a specific state.

I'd like to add one more thing: it might even be a *bad* idea to give that state (identified as $Z_{1}|\mathrm{GHZ}\rangle$) a specific name, because (as you may be well aware) $Z_{1}|\mathrm{GHZ}\rangle = Z_{2}|\mathrm{GHZ}\rangle = Z_{3}|\mathrm{GHZ}\rangle$. This could create some unwarranted ambiguity.

If you identify the state as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|000\rangle - |111\rangle)$ you don't have this problem, of course.

Also, it may be of interest to note that the $|\mathrm{GHZ}\rangle$ state (generalized to $n$ qubits) is [often used](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0409201) in anonymous quantum networking, precisely because of the fact that such a local phase flip has a completely non-local effect, thereby hiding the identity of the party applying the phase flip.

Now, this may be **really** out of focus, but there's one other thing that might be of interest to you. You might now that the $\mathrm{GHZ}$ state is (up to local Cliffords) equivalent to a [graph state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_state). Moreover, in [this review paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0602096) they introduce (Eq. $(28)$, page $16$) the set of states $\{|W\rangle = Z_{W}|G\rangle\}$, where $|G\rangle$ is a graph state. This set forms an orthonormal basis, and if the $|\mathrm{GHZ}\rangle$ state were a graph state your state $Z_{1}|\mathrm{GHZ}\rangle$ would be an element of this basis, namely $|W_{100}\rangle$. However, the $\mathrm{GHZ}$ state is only equivalent to a graph state, so it doesn't really work. (If it were to work, we would have $|W_{100}\rangle = |W_{010}\rangle = |W_{001}\rangle$, which is clearly not possible for a basis!)